# ValueError Versus TypeError, Why?

Tags: python, object, blackjack

The Error output: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'yes'"

I know it is obvious that I AM WRONG, but I do not understand why. When I try to convert a string to an int, I expected to get a TypeError, not a ValueError.

Please Explain as I was under the impression ValueError was when the correct type was passed into a built-in function, but with an invalid value. It would seem then that you can pass any type into int(), but if the value isnt base 10, then we execute a ValueError instead?

```
def place_bet(self):

        while True:
            response = input("Make Bet (1/2/5/10/25/50/100): ")

            try:
                current_bet = int(response)
            except TypeError:
                print("Please Enter a Valid number")

            else: 
                if current_bet not in (1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100):
                    print("Sorry, only bets of exactly 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50 & 100 are allowed.")
                else:
                     self.balance -= current_bet
                     self.bet = current_bet
                     print(f"${self.bet} BET PLACED")
                     break
```

Answer (score 2):

In python it is valid to pass a string type to the int function.  However, if it cannot be parsed to an integer you will get the ValueError you have described.

You may want to wrap your attempt to parse a string to an integer in a try catch construct, such as seen here:
[How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Comment: Thank you! This concisely and explicitly answer my question